# How to get the order details of a customer using the access token of other customer?

Tags: orders, api, magento2.2.2

In my project there the two types of users: manager and captain.
The manager should be able to view the orders placed by captain so i need to use the access token of manager to get the order list of captain using the search criteria API /V1/mine/orders. Please help me to suggest how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.